# Image Fusion by Principal Component Analysis(PCA)

Tags: c++, image, opencv, pca, fusion

I tried to implement PCA based image fusion with C++ and OpenCV,  but I can't understand,  that exactly I have to do. As I read in some of tutorials on PCA based image fusion, when there are two pictures I1 and I2 of the same scene of sizes NxM in greyscale, algorithm is:

1. Create a matrix of size NMx2, where column 1 is a pixel  values of I1, and column 2 is a pixel  values of I2 .
2. In some of tutorials that I found this is necessary to find average value of 1 column and extract it from 1 column, and average value of 2 column and extract it from second column. Is it necessary?
3. Find  a covariance matrix of this matrix MNx2.
4. Find eigenvalues and eigenvectors of this covariance matrix.
   In one of tutorials, I read that it necessary to choose an eigenvector, which is corresponding to larger eigenvalue and normalize this eigenvector.
   In OpenCV, when use cv::eigen() function, it returns eigenvectors, which yet are normalized. And in one of tutorials, I read that sum of obtained components should be P1+P2=1.

So, if I get eigenvector, correcponding to larger eigenvalue, for example like this `eigen = (0,705353; 0,71453) = (u, v)`, that is a formula for fused image `I_fus`?
`I_fus = u*I1+v*I2`? Or 
`I_fus =   u/(u+v)*I1+v/(u+v)*I2`?
Or I wrong and there is another formula for fused image?